# Replacing a substring

Tags: r, regex

Hoping to get some guidance as only an occasional analyst and couldn't really understand how to manage an expression with a preceding numeric value.

My data below, I am hoping to convert the "4D" and "5D" type of data into "4 Door" and "5 Door".

```
a <- c("4D Sedan", "5D Wagon")
b <- c("4 Door Sedan", "5 Door Wagon")
dt <- cbind(a,b)
```

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub()` here, searching for the pattern:

```
\\b(\\d+)D\\b
```

and replacing it with:

```
\\1 Door
```

**Code:**

```
a <- c("4D Sedan", "5D Wagon", "AB4D car 5D")
> gsub("\\b(\\d+)D\\b", "\\1 Door", a)
[1] "4 Door Sedan"    "5 Door Wagon"    "AB4D car 5 Door"
```

Note in the above example that the `4D` in `AB4D car 5D` does *not* get replaced, nor would we want this to happen.  By using word boundaries in `\\b(\\d+)D\\b` we can avoid unwanted replacements from happening.

Comment: thanks, just so that I can understand fully, in the replacement "\\1 Door", does the "1" stand for any numerical value?

Comment: No, `\\1` is the first _capture group_, which is the quantity in parentheses in the pattern we used to search, i.e. `(\\d+)`.  In other words, it is the _number_ in front of `D`, assuming we matched that pattern.